Dependency Conflict with ngx-bootstrap and @formio/angular After Upgrading to Angular 16
I am working on an Angular project that I recently upgraded from Angular 15 to Angular 16. After the upgrade, I am facing several dependency conflicts with ngx-bootstrap and @formio/angular packages. When I run npm install, I get the following error:
(https://i.sstatic.net/6EUUYWBM.png)
Problem:
How can I resolve this dependency conflict between ngx-bootstrap and @formio/angular while keeping my project on Angular 16? Are there any specific versions I should use or any alternatives that would help me maintain compatibility?
Current Angular Version: Angular 16.2.12
Dependencies Involved:
ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0 requires angular 15
@formio/angular@6.0.0 requires ngx-bootstrap@^10.2.0

I have tried
Installing ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2 which supports Angular 16.
Expected this version to resolve the conflict since it supports Angular 16.
This caused a conflict with @formio/angular@6.0.0, which requires ngx-bootstrap@^10.2.0.
Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "angular",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "IE 11"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/elements": "16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@formio/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-split": "^3.0.2",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^13.0.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^16.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "brace": "^0.11.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.4",
    "chartjs-chart-treemap": "^2.3.1",
    "chartjs-gauge": "^0.3.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "core-js": "^3.30.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.12",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.3.0",
    "ngx-color": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-cron-jobs": "^18.2.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-img": "^10.19.0",
    "ngx-joyride": "^2.5.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^14.0.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "pace-js": "^1.2.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
    "quill-mention": "^4.1.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "svelte": "^4.2.2",
    "svelte-gantt": "^4.4.2",
    "typeface-exo": "^0.0.22",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.2.12",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^16.2.14",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "@types/chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.5",
    "@types/d3-color": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/estree": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.6.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.196",
    "@types/node": "^22.5.0",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.10",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "5.0.0",
    "husky": "8.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "npm": "^8.19.4",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^4.0.2",
    "stylelint": "^15.7.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9"
  }
}


please share package.json

you can try npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Did you install formio with the command npm install --save @formio/angular@a16?

Yes. I have already tried both.

Looking at "@formio/angular@6.0.0"'s package.json at tag v6.0.0 on github it is compatible with "@angular/common": "^16.0.4", and requires "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2"; --> it is compatible with angular 16.2.12
This incompatibility message you are getting seems odd...
I think you need to delete your node_modules folder as well as your package-lock.json file and try installing all packages again to resolve your dependency issues.
Try using the force flag as well if it does not work without it:
npm install --force


Thank you for your suggestion! I have already tried deleting the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and then running npm install again. Unfortunately, the issue persists.
Additionally, I tried using the --force flag with npm install, but it didn't resolve the dependency conflicts. It seems like there is still an incompatibility with @angular/common@16.2.12

I picked up your question's package.json file and placed it in a new empty folder, I than executed npm i --force from it. It worked... You have a lot of other conflicts though (which using the force command ignores). not sure if your app will work, but npm install --force certainly does.

While installing formio/angular with Angular 16, I noticed some dependency issues that might be related. Specifically, during the installation process:
With Angular 16, the formio/angular package requires a peer dependency on ngx-bootstrap version 10.0.2, as indicated in the package-lock.json.https://i.sstatic.net/v8TSMbSo.png
However, with Angular 17, it seems to allow peer dependencies for 'ngx-bootstrap' versions 10, 11, or 12. https://i.sstatic.net/Xtn9jdcg.png
This difference in peer dependencies could lead to potential conflicts when installing or updating packages.

There is plenty of dependency issues on your listed libraries other than ngx-bootstrap... Also, as per my above link, @formio/angular@6.0.0 lists as dependency ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2. So in answering your question, using  npm i --force will resolve the question listed issue. Please fell free to ask other questions after finding the next road block... but for this question that is all you need...
